# parsing time """" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse """ as "2006"

Tags: go

I am trying to unmarshal some json into a struct and have the following:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

type Added struct {
    Added *time.Time `json:"added"`
}

func main() {
    st := strings.NewReader(`{"added": ""}`)

    a := &Added{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(st).Decode(&a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(a)

}
```

Running the above results in:

```
panic: parsing time """" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse """ as "2006"
```

Ok, so I try a custom marshaller:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

type Added struct {
    Added *MyTime `json:"added"`
}

func main() {
    st := strings.NewReader(`{"added": ""}`)

    a := &Added{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(st).Decode(&a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(a)

}

type MyTime struct {
    *time.Time
}

func (m *MyTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Ignore null, like in the main JSON package.
    if string(data) == "null" || string(data) == `""` {
        return nil
    }
    // Fractional seconds are handled implicitly by Parse.
    tt, err := time.Parse(`"`+time.RFC3339+`"`, string(data))
    *m = MyTime{&tt}
    return err
}
```

I then get:

```
&{%!v(PANIC=runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference)}
```

Ok, now what do I do? I'd simply like to handle the "" value from the json.

My [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NZXCXIyRZ_f) with the complete example is found.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> import "time"
>
> [type Time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time)
>
> A Time represents an instant in time with nanosecond precision.
>
> Programs using times should typically store and pass them as values,
>   not pointers. That is, time variables and struct fields should be of
>   type time.Time, not *time.Time.

---

I just kept fixing likely problems, for example, `time.Time`, not `*time.Time`, a real date, and so on, until I got a reasonable result:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

type MyTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (m *MyTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Ignore null, like in the main JSON package.
    if string(data) == "null" || string(data) == `""` {
        return nil
    }
    // Fractional seconds are handled implicitly by Parse.
    tt, err := time.Parse(`"`+time.RFC3339+`"`, string(data))
    *m = MyTime{tt}
    return err
}

type Added struct {
    Added MyTime `json:"added"`
}

func main() {
    st := strings.NewReader(`{"added": "2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"}`)

    var a Added
    err := json.NewDecoder(st).Decode(&a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Uusdp3DkXDU

Output:

```
{2012-04-23 18:25:43.511 +0000 UTC}
```

With an empty (`""`) date string, the `time.Time` zero value, `0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC`:

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/eQoEyqBlhg2

Output:

```
{0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}
```

Use the `time` `IsZero` method to test for the zero value.

> [func (Time) IsZero](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.IsZero)
>
> ```
> func (t Time) IsZero() bool
> ```
>
> IsZero reports whether t represents the zero time instant, January 1,
>   year 1, 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: This is so smart. I would have given 100 votes if I could :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you were very close to the solution with your custom marshaller. Maybe just revert to normal decoding for normal dates. This may help:

```
type MyTime time.Time

func (m *MyTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // Ignore null, like in the main JSON package.
    if string(data) == "null" || string(data) == `""` {
        return nil
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(data, (*time.Time)(m))
}
```